# Is this worth doing for practice and learning, without modules (Perl)

Tags: perl

looking into connecting to a secure ftp site (using perl), and downloading all the .log files, saving in new directories named after the day I downloaded the files.  I want to do this without modules, as a learning experience, but before I start I wanted to know if you guys thought it was doing, or is way too much for a relatively new programmer and I should just learn the modules?

Answer (score 11):

If it's production work, no, use the modules.  Your implementation will be buggy, missing features and unknown to the next person maintaining that code.

Otherwise, yes.  It's good to learn the principles of a network protocol.  I do have a reservation about FTP as it is a bit baroque, insecure, inefficient and on its way out.  scp, HTTP or rsync would be more useful to put your energy into.

I'd start with [reading the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and putting together your own FTP module using just network sockets.  Document and test it as if you were going to release to CPAN as a full learning exercise in making a network module.  Run it against some various FTP server implementations as they often interpret the spec differently (or not at all).  Don't be afraid to cheat and look at what the existing modules do.  Who knows, you might write something better than what's already there.

Answer (score 5):

Learning the principals, just like we did at school for long multiplication and division, means we know how things work when we use a short hand.

However, when new to the world,just like when you learn to speak, you did "A is for Apple" etc, you didnt get explained about the finesse of grammar and all that, you learnt to express yourself enough to be understood.

Programming is a little like the same. While in an ideal world you can easily argue a prewritten generic library is often way less efficient than a specifically targeted set of routines. If the wheel you are using was already invented, it seems a lot of work to make a new one.

So, use the wheels and cogs afailable, once you really have the hang of it, NOW look at inventing your own more efficient ones.

Comment: And knowing how things work inside is invaluable when things go wrong. A big pile of magical libraries is great when things work but when things don't work, you need to what's probably going on behind the scenes or you won't know how to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ad cpan modules:

- Modules are an great learning source. Here is zilion modules and you can really learn much studying some of them.
- And when/while you mastering your perl, you will start writing you own modules. When your program will use modules anyway (yours one), you can ask - why don't use modules already developed and debugged?

So, learn perl basics, study some modules (for example Net::SFTP) and if you still want write your own solution - it is up to you. :)

'